# How to scrape the "cardinal_id" from this page

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I am trying to get the cardinal_id from a webpage. The only reference I can find to it in the source code is this

```
Cardinal.on('payments.setupComplete', function(setupCompleteData){
  $('<input>', {
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'cardinal_id',
    value: setupCompleteData.sessionId}).appendTo('#checkout_form');
  $('#cnb').change(function() {
    Cardinal.trigger("accountNumber.update", $(this).val().replace(/\s+/g, ''));
  });      
});
```

Does anyone know how I might go about getting this ID?

Thanks.

Comment: @mplungjan I suppose but I typed that in the console and got nothing.

Comment: So you actually mean `$("[name=cardinal_id]").val()` but not until the setup is complete

Comment: @mplungian I suppose it's because it is the session ID of the input into the function so I'm not sure how to find where this function is being called and what with.

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks that worked. Is there any way I can get it by just using python requests?

Comment: Perhaps - you will need to find the setupcompletedata

Comment: @mplungjan I have no idea how to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not with the content you have posted so far. Also I do not do python